# Baseline align spinner to TextInputLayout in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-constraintlayout

I need to baseline align a `Spinner` to an `TextInputLayout` in `ConstraintLayout`.
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_values"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textInputLayout"

    />
```

Values for `@array/spinner_values`:

```
<string-array name="spinner_values">
    <item>hello</item>
</string-array>
```

and this is the result:
[image]

Obviously the `Spinner` baseline is not aligned with the baseline of the `TextInputLayout`. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `TextInputLayout` does not providing Baseline with its parent layout.
Try below it may help you.

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getBaseline()
    {
        EditText editText = getEditText();
        return editText.getPaddingTop() + editText.getBaseline();
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, it works. Thank you! Do know why there is no working implementation provided for getBaseline by default? Can't understand that.